# Change current image on event hover or click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm newbie in jquery. I use this code for changing the current image on hover or click by another  with jquery. But it dosn't work!!

```
<head>
<title> Visite  </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$('img').hover(function () {
  $(this).attr('src', 'o.184684.jpg');
})
</script>   
</head>

<body>
<img src="logo11w.png" alt="photo" />
</body>
</html>
```

i give this example from http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/8H4MC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the jQuery code in a document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').hover(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', 'o.184684.jpg');
    });
});
```

Or alternatively

```
$(function() {
    $('img').hover(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', 'o.184684.jpg');
    });
});
```

This will only give you the mouse over. You may need to pass in the mouse out function as well: [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$(function() {
    $('img').hover(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', 'o.184684.jpg');
    }, function() {
        //mouse out function
    });
});
```